# Reference image in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I have found that I can add images to cells as background in Numbers in various sheets.

I'd like to reference these images in these cells from another sheet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t believe it is possible to reference the image in a cell of another table but you can simulate the effect with an appropriately filtered overlapping table.

One solution is to copy each of your images into a row or column with formulas in each cell deciding if the picture should be shown and use filter/sort options to show only the chosen sets. The formula results can be made transparent so only the image is seen. Conditional highlighting with custom transparent background can also be used to knock some sets out of view while preserving absential space so the images line up as they should, or alternatively to have a toggle switch to show/hide the picture.

Here are some tips I’ve found useful:
If your images change frequently it’s helpful to use the same formulas for all cells using col() or row() as index holders for one dimension and a reference to header column or row as an index in another dimension. This minimizes maintenance time when new images are added. In this example, the 11 columns with olive-toned headers are all separate tables of one column and many rows. The formulas in each cell checks if a given title (represented by the position index) is present in a column of a book display (in the yellow table identified by the number in each olive header row) and the tables are then filtered for true values.

BTW, Here is the formula in each picture cell:
CHOOSE(IFERROR(MATCH(LOOKUP(ROW()−1,Paperback Lookup::Table 1::$A,Paperback Lookup::Table 1::$B),CHOOSE(A$1,Book Plan::B,Book Plan::C,Book Plan::D,Book Plan::E,Book Plan::F,Book Plan::G,Book Plan::H,Book Plan::I,Book Plan::J,Book Plan::K,Book Plan::L),0)^0,2),TRUE,FALSE)

[image: Book Diplay]